# displaytag.properties location in a maven web project

Tags: eclipse, maven, jboss, properties, displaytag

In a maven web project (developed with Eclipse on JBoss), I have put the file **displaytag.properties**

```
paging.banner.placement=both
```

in the following three locations:

```
/myapp/src/main/java/displaytag.properties

/myapp/src/main/resources/displaytag.properties

/myapp/src/displaytag.properties
```

However, the file is not recognized. It does not affect the produced table.

Any ideas how I could understand what is wrong?

From [DisplayTag Configuration properties](http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/11/configuration.html):

> For the whole web application, create a custom properties file named
>   displaytag.properties and place it in the application classpath
>   (tipically into WEB-INF/classes). Displaytag will use the locale of
>   the request object to determine the locale of the property file to
>   use; if the key required does not exist in the specified file, the key
>   will be loaded from a more general property file.

There is no `WEB-INF/classes` in my folder structure, since this folder was not created by Maven.

**UPDATE:**

I've found out the reason why my properties files were not copied from `/myapp/src/main/resources/*.properties` to `WEB-INF/classes` in the generated war file. I've had the following setting in my pom file:

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <includes>
            <include>applicationContext.xml</include>
            <include>security-config.xml</include>
        </includes>
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <targetPath>WEB-INF/classes</targetPath>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
        <directory>../src/main/resources</directory>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/*.properties</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WEB-INF/classes` is the location where the classes of a webapp are found at runtime, inside the generated war file. The goal of Maven is to generate this war file. Check if the file is indeed in the war file generated by Maven.

The appropriate location for such a file in a Maven project is `/myapp/src/main/resources/displaytag.properties`. The files in this location are considered as resources which must be copied along with the classes in the generated artefact. If it's not the case, it means that the resources plugin isn't used, or is configured in a way that excludes this file or gets resources from another directory.

Comment: Thank you. As far as I know, the resources plugin is supposed to be called by default when I call the install plugin. Am I correct?

Comment: I think so, yes, but I'm no Maven expert, and I hate it. It might depend on the artefact type, but I don't see why it would be disabled for a war.

Comment: You have pointed me in the right direction. The properties file was not copied to the `WEB-INF/classes` at the war file. And the reason for this was the pom file (see update above). Thank you.